# How to validate both @PathVariable and @RequestBody in one ConstraintValidator in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, validation, bean-validation

I have an endpoint handler method in controller:

```
@PutMapping("/users/{userId}")
public UserDto updateUser(@PathVariable UUID userId, @RequestBody UserRequestDto updateRequest) {
  ...
}
```

Inside the `UserRequestDto` object I have an `email` field.

I would like to validate if the `email` value is not already in use.

It is not a problem for the creation as I only need to check if the email is not in the database. I've created a simple ConstraintValidator and everything is working.

But for the update, I need to check if the updated email address is not used by someone else and omit the currently update user. So I need to operate on both `userId` and `updateRequest` at once. Is it doable to create custom ConstraintValidator to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Since you posted code from a `@RestController`, I assume we are talking about validation at the controller level. I can share a few observations:

1) Note that you are trying to put business logic related validation into a `ConstraintValidator`. In your case it is validating fields from a *data transfer object* (i.e. `UserRequestDto`) that holds request attributes. At the controller level we should only be validating the request itself (i.e. "was all necessary information provided so I can actually start performing the operation?").

2) Because the understanding of "valid" will most likely differ from business use case to business use case, business logic related validation should go into a `@Service` bean where use case specific validation can be performed (such as "is there any other user with the same username or email?"). Most of the time this is done by manually checking different conditions, such as performing database queries or consulting other applications. At this level `ConstraintValidator`s are counterproductive.

3) `ConstraintValidator`s are most of the time used to perform a syntactical validation (i.e. "are all necessary values present in the expected format?") but not so much for semantical validation (i.e. "is the information correct according to the my business logic (which might involve database queries and consulting other applications)?").

So in your case, validating your `UserRequestDto` object using a custom  `ConstraintValidator` is absolutely fine if you need to check whether all required attributes have been passed by the client in a specific format. However, checking if a username/email is already taken by another user should be performed by the logic layer in a use case specific manner - outside of a `ConstraintValidator`.

Answer (score 2):

You can annotate your controller (class-level) with Spring's `@Validated` and then `@NotBlank @PathVariable String something` will work as well.

Spring will create an AOP proxy around all your methods and will look for JSR 303 annotations on every parameter but it will not touch `@RequestBody`, so for the body, you still must add `@Valid` which will be inspected by the standard means.

Also, see this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26219

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches I could think of:

Approach 1:

> Put a unique constraint on email id in your database schema. If you
>   try to save/update an already used email id, a constrain violation
>   exception will be thrown.

Approach 2:

> While researching on the above topic I came across the [link](http://dolszewski.com/spring/custom-validation-annotation-in-spring/). You
>   can refer it once and see if your need is sufficed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Class-Level Constrains:

> Last but not least, a constraint can also be placed on the class level. In this case not a single property is subject of the validation but the complete object. Class-level constraints are useful if the validation depends on a correlation between several properties of an object.

You can access more details from https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.1#validator-usingvalidator-classlevel